# For loop syntax conventions

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

In python when iterating with a for loop, when do we use `for x in y` versus for `x,y in z`.

My guess is that it depends on the iterable, and if so, could you explain to me the general conventions?

i.e when you use the enumerate function it's `for x,y, in z`.

Thanks all

Comment: What you see is another feature of Python. It can unpack iterables in variables given in tuple form. So your example requires `z` to contain iterables that contains two values.

Comment: Thanks for that! If it's not much of a problem could you further exemplify that? What are some examples of iterables with two values? Dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a  structure from iterable, you need to put a pattern between `for` and `in`

Iterating over `names = ['joe', 'chloe', 'karen']` is something you already know.

However you can capture any number of linear values.

```
>>> res = [['joe',1,2], ['chloe',2,3]]
>>> for name, tag1, tag2 in res:
...     print(name, tag1, tag2)
...
joe 1 2
chloe 2 3
```

or,

```
>>> res = [['joe', 1,2,3], ['chloe', 3,4]]
>>> for name, first, *rest in  res:
...     print(name, first, rest)
...
joe 1 [2, 3]
chloe 3 [4]
```

Unpacking a dict is same as list.

```
>>> tps = [('adam', 31, {'a': '1', 'b': 2}), ('karen', 21, {'b': 3, 'a': 9})]

>>> for name, age, keys in tps:
...     print(name, age, keys['a'])
...
adam 31 1
karen 21 9


>>> for name, age, keys in tps:
...     print(name, age, [k for k in keys])
...
adam 31 ['a', 'b']
karen 21 ['b', 'a']


>>> for name, age, *keys in tps: 
...     print(name, age, [k for k in keys])
...
adam 31 [{'a': '1', 'b': 2}]
karen 21 [{'b': 3, 'a': 9}]
```

**enumerate object**

```
 |  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from start, which
 |  defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

So, one can unpack `enumerate(ys)` as `x, y` where x is index of y in ys collection.

Comment: Please improve your answer and use correct upper case letters.

Comment: finally, after two years :)

Comment: Please improve your comment and use correct upper case letters. Thanks in advance.